# adding and sorting a column in sql

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, multiple-columns

I am trying to combine two tables in sql and am having trouble.

table g looks like this

```
    id         name
*************************
  1234         john
  3456         sarah
  7890         ben
```

table f looks like this

```
    id         count
**************************
   3456          2
   1234          7
   7890          5
```

I would like to insert a column into table g equal to the count in table f, sorted according to ID.

I've tried using the INNER JOIN and UNION commands, but neither of them seem to have worked. Does anyone know a solution? it seems like a pretty common problem.

Comment: You want to join the tables and write a query that outputs the count sorted by ID(simple join) or you want to insert another column into table g - basically merge the two tables? (why?)

Comment: @Joel, honestly, you told you want to `insert a column` so honestly which of below answers can be accepted?

Comment: @FarhangAmary Sometimes the author accepts what works best fr him/her; that doesn't neccessarily mean your answer is wrong. In my opinion, your answer is about as effective as mine.

Comment: @Isaiah, really my problem is not that, I have wrote the answer before you but only for extra description and wants in the question, I completed it and it was posted just a few second later. I just want users who post questions be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT g.id, g.name, f.count
FROM f,g
WHERE f.id = g.id
ORDER BY g.id;
```

The above is a simple join query.

In simple join queries, you select the information you want from both tables and set the where condition to be equal to the rows you want to join.

Also, you probably should set f.id and g.id as primary keys and set f.id as a foreign key reference to g.id.

Comment: If you want to store this for later use, you can edit the above to `CREATE VIEW my_view AS SELECT…` and you can later run queries on those results like a normal table!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want a select like this:

```
select g.id,g.name,f.count
from go
     join f on g.id=f.id
order by g.id
```

but if you really want to phisicaly add a column(`count`) to table `g` and update it as mentioned in question you can do this:

```
alter table g 
add column count int
```

and update the tale `g` like this:

```
update table g
set g.count=f.count
from g
     join f on g.id=f.id
```